# How to set jQuery slider value in the middle

Tags: jquery, uislider

I am using jQuery Slider (http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) for slider element. By default, the min and max values remains at start and end of slider. After user moves a slider and takes lower value somewhere in between, it refreshes the page but lower value still points to start. I want to keep it where user selected it before page refresh. How this can be achieved with this jQuery slider ?

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code can help you achieve that behaviour

[Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6eqsLkrz/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var sliderValue = 0;
if(localStorage.getItem("slider-value") !== undefined && localStorage.getItem("slider-value") !== ""){
    sliderValue = localStorage.getItem("slider-value");
}

$("#slider-value").text(sliderValue);

$( "#slider" ).slider({
        value: sliderValue,
        slide: function( event, ui ) { 
            $( "#slider-value" ).html( ui.value ); 
            localStorage.setItem("slider-value", ui.value);
        }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Store the value in Session or Cookie then set the default value of your slider according to your stored value.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp